# docker-compose not following my volume mapping, how do I fix it?

Tags: docker, airflow

I have an apache/airflow image I build using this [docker-compose file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.6.0/docker-compose.yaml). The airflow documentation says to create a `./dags ./logs ./plugins`. Instead I have them mapped inside an airflow folder like so (the folders are already created on my local machine)

```
  volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

I also tried

```
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./airflow}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./airflow}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-./airflow}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

Commands I run to start the container : `docker-compose up airflow-init` then `docker-compose up`

Why does the docker-compose file create the dags, logs, and plugins folder outside the airflow folder? Are these mapped wrong?

Comment: `the docker-compose file insist` ? What does that mean? Docker-compose is a file, it can't "insist". What _happens_? What does not happen? What commands do you execute and what happens on execution of those?

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear. Correct, I attached a link to the docker-compose file. However, I edited the volumes because I want them to be in an airflow folder but when I start the docker-compose file it creates the folders in the main directory.

Comment: I still do not understand. You have an empty directory in which you downloaded the docker-compose file from airflow documentation. You edit the file by prefixing volumes with `./airflow`. Then you execute `docker-compose up` command. _Then_ you see that a directory is created `dags` instead of `airflow/dags`. Is that true? What about `AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR` environment variable? `docker-compose file create` Docker-compose file is a file, it's static. A command may create something. What commands did you execute?

Comment: I run `docker-compose up airflow-init` then `docker-compose up`. I removed `AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR` environment variable because it wasn't working as expected. It kept creating folders outside of the airflow folder. Obviously, removing it didn't help either.